# How is data saves in admin_user table

Tags: magento-1.8, database, permissions, user-roles

How should I insert data via in admin_user table via admin/permission/ create user.

Comment: Sorry, but what is your actual question? What have you tried so far, and where does a problem occur?

Answer (score 0):

you should play around with `Mage::getModel('admin/user');`

Load user 
`$user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load('$admin_user_id');`

Load All admin user's

`$collection = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->getCollection();`